# How to call javascript on angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have javascript file from assets/js/chartrank.js

**chartrank.js**

```
function chartRank() {
    // do something
}
```

and call a function defined in it on `rankuser` component but it doesn't work.

**rankuser.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import "../../assets/js/chartrank.js";
declare var jsObject: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rankuser',
  templateUrl: './rankuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rankuser.component.css']
})
export class RankuserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    jsObject.chartRank();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR ReferenceError: jsObject is not defined
```

Please help.

Comment: Try doing import * as jsObject from "../../assets/js/chartrank.js"

Comment: Thank you very much, but not work.

Comment: can you create a plunker for it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`import` doesn't work here because `chartrank.js` doesn't export anything.

The simplest way here is adding `chartrank.js` to `.angular-cli.json`'s **scripts** array, and declare the `chartRank`(**function name**) as a global variable.

.angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
  "./assets/js/chartrank.js"
],
```

component or service

```
declare var chartRank: any;

@Component({
  ...
})
export class RankuserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    chartRank();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a module with @Injectable decorator like this

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class MyClass{

  constructor() {}

  chartRank() {
    // do something
   }
}
```

Then in component

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MyClass} from "..myClass"
declare var jsObject: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rankuser',
  templateUrl: './rankuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rankuser.component.css']
})
export class RankuserComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private mc:MyClass) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    mc.chartRank();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```