# Why my button doesn't trigger my javascript function?

Tags: angular, typescript, alert

I have one form-validation sample. If I press submit button, it is has to show alert message but it is not showing.

> This is my sample:
>   [sample link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validation-cmusqh?file=app/reactive-form.component.html)

Please help me to get this done.

I have tried like this:

```js
//button declaration

<button id="validateSubmit" [disabled]="reactForm.invalid" onclick="myFunction()" class="samplebtn e-control e-btn e-primary"
                            type="submit" style="height:40px;width: 150px;" data-ripple="true">Submit</button>
                            
//function for showing alert message
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert('your form is submitted');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Really important to respect the code convention. In computer programming, an indentation style is a convention governing the indentation of blocks of code to convey program structure. However, some languages (such as Python and occam) use indenting to determine the structure instead of using braces or keywords; this is termed the off-side rule.

If you make some multi-space like you did, it will create an error as it will consider your `class` attribute value would be `samplebtn e-control e-btn e-primary"
                            type="submit" style="height:40px;width: 150px;" data-ripple="true">`.

Then after it, it thinks the `Submit` is another attribute of your `button`. That is why it created the error where it didn't know how to handle your `<` after.

So again, in order to avoid that error, please respect the convention as below and it will work great.

## Same line convention

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('your form is submitted');
}
```

```html
<button id="validateSubmit" [disabled]="reactForm.invalid" onclick="myFunction()" class="samplebtn e-control e-btn e-primary" type="submit" style="height:40px; width: 150px;" data-ripple="true">Submit</button>
```

## Indentation convention

One other way to write it is to indented every attributes.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('your form is submitted');
}
```

```html
<button
  id="validateSubmit"
  [disabled]="reactForm.invalid"
  onclick="myFunction()"
  class="samplebtn e-control e-btn e-primary"
  type="submit"
  style="height:40px;width: 150px;"
  data-ripple="true">Submit</button>
```

Comment: No doubt it's working, but you should at least tell what you changed to make it work.

Comment: can you please tell me what did you change?... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validation-cmusqh?file=app/reactive-form.component.html

Comment: Hahaha np, anytime my friend!

Answer (score -1):

> Ideally its best to use typescript itself to your action. if so move your function to typescript file itself rather than in script.[Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-validation-3s9whp)

If you want to use javascript from angular [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524723/how-to-call-javascript-on-angular-2)

*You could find errors from the console window which helps to debug.*

```
export class ReactiveFormReactiveComponent implements OnInit {

reactForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
  this.reactForm = new FormGroup({
    'check': new FormControl('required', [FormValidators.required]),
    'email_check': new FormControl('someone@gmail.com', [FormValidators.email]),
    'url_check': new FormControl('www.anything.com', [FormValidators.url]),

  });
}

ngOnInit(): void {

}

get check() { return this.reactForm.get('check'); }


  myFunction() {
     alert('your form is submitted');
 }

}
```